# antlr grammar that enforces division before multiplication in a complex expression

Tags: antlr4

I am kind of new to antlr. I have written the grammar below to perform some arithmetic expressions such as 2+3*3/2*2. However, instead of getting 11, I get 4.25. Surely, this confirms that the expression is evaluated from right to left. Can anyone help with the grammar I have below so that I can at least get 11 as my answer. In order words, I want to enforce basic BODMAS operation i.e division before multiplication. Thanks in advance.

```
My Grammar:

compute:   expr ; 
expr:   expr op=('*'|'/') expr          #mulDiv  
    |   expr op=('+'|'-') expr          #addSub 
    | INT                               #int
    ; 


My Visitor:
@Override public Double visitMulDiv(ExpressionParser.MulDivContext ctx) { 
        double left = visit(ctx.expr(0));  // get value of left expression  
        double right = visit(ctx.expr(1)); // get value of right expression
        if ( ctx.op.getText().equals("*")){
            return left * right;
        }else{
            return left / right; 
        }   
    }
@Override public Double visitAddSub(ExpressionParser.AddSubContext ctx) { 
        double left = visit(ctx.expr(0));  // get value of left expression  
        double right = visit(ctx.expr(1)); // get value of right expression
        if ( ctx.op.getText().equals("+")){
            return left + right;
        }else{
            return left - right; 
        }   
    }
@Override public Double visitInt(ExpressionParser.IntContext ctx) { 
        return Double.valueOf(ctx.INT().getText());
    }
```

Comment: Surprisingly, [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=2%2B3*3%2F2*2&oq=2%2B3*3%2F2*2&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j69i64.399j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) evaluates this to 11

Comment: Yes, even with a scientific calculator, its 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Division before multiplication might work like this:

```
expr : expr '/' expr             #div
     | expr '*' expr             #mul  
     | expr op=('+'|'-') expr    #addSub 
     | INT                       #int
     ;
```

Comment: Thanks  for you response, I had already tried this before checking your post and it worked. I have also posted the modified grammar i used.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to solve the problem. Here is the grammar that does what I needed.

```
expr: expr '/' expr                                 #div
| expr '*' expr                                     #mul 
| expr '-' expr                                     #sub
| expr '+' expr                                     #add
```